# XMLHttpRequest not working after IE 11 Update 11.0.17

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have an existing webpage that loaded info from a text file and was working in IE 11 - update 11.0.16

After updating to IE 11 - update 11.0.17 this function no longer works.  Function stops at .responseText  and doesn't continue.

The page/function continues to work when using Chrome and Firefox.  (...IE is company standard)

```js
var fileRqst = new XMLHttpRequest();
var fileURL = 'http://STS/timeclock/user.txt';

fileRqst.open('GET', fileURL, false);
fileRqst.setRequestHeader('User-Agent', navigator.userAgent);
fileRqst.send(null);

if (fileRqst.status == 200) {
   document.getElementById("Grid1").innerHTML = fileRqst.responseText; 
                                  // <<<<<<<<<< fileRqst.responseTest; FAILS!!!
} else {
    alert(fileRqst.status + " Error in XMLHttpRequest call! Unable to load report table.");
}
```

Any work arounds? Any related issues with IE 11 update 11.0.17?

Comment: Open the browser's developer tools. Are there any error messages? Does the Net tab show the request being made successfully?

Comment: Unknown runtime error and Net tab is empty

Comment: "Unknown runtime error" — Does it tell you which line the error is on? What if you add some `console.log` statements to figure out where it is getting to.

Comment: document.getElementById("Grid1").innerHTML = hRequest.responseText;

Comment: Put a breakpoint on or before that line, copy the responseText someplace you can more easily read it, and make sure that it is actually valid HTML.

Comment: ResponseText is valid TR/TD formatting and table displays correctly for IE 11 update 11.0.16, Chrome and Firefox -  ResponseText only failing when using IE 11 update 11.0.17 - JavaScript processing just ends.

Comment: I'm also observing issues with 11.0.17 and AJAX. I can navigate the website in question just fine, until I make an AJAX request - interestingly, the AJAX request itself usually succeeds, and I can often make one more request before the whole site breaks down. Sometimes, the page freezes. Clearing the cache in IE fixes the issue until the next time I make an AJAX request. It's hard to narrow the issue down right now, because the site in question is of course a bunch of huge hacks (`no-cache`, facebook, google+...).